# В linux mint постоянно циклически выбрасывает в окно авторизации

Tags: linux, linux-mint

В очередной раз заходя в linux mint столкнулся с постоянной циклической авторизацией. При вводе правильного логина и пароля все равно выбрасывает в это же окно ввода логина и пароля и так постоянно. В чем может быть дело и как исправить данную ситуацию?

Comment: Случайно не chromium браузером пользуетесь?

Comment: Нет, был установлен Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте войти в сессию через консоль. `Ctrl+Alt+F1`.
Текстовый экран предложит ввести имя логина и пароль. Если войдет, введите startx (или startxfce4 или gnome-session)

Можно попробовать:   Авторизируйтесь через консоль. Теперь удалите файл `.Xauthority` из домашнего каталога: `rm .Xauthority .ICEauthority`. Также можно очистить кэш, чтобы освободить место на диске:`rm -Rf .cache`.Возвращайтесь на экран входа `Ctrl+Alt+F7`.

Если этот метод не помог, необходимо произвести дополнительные манипуляции:
`strace -f -o /tmp/x.log startx` - если есть какие-либо ошибки, то :  следует проверить права на файл .Xauthority `ls -la /home/имя_пользователя/.Xauthority`.
При необходимости изменить права файла с root на пользователя из под которого невозможно произвести стандартный вход с графическим окружением:`sudo chown имя_пользователя:имя_пользователя /home/имя_пользователя/.Xauthority`

А вообще-то что не так должно быть в ~/.xsession-errors .

Еще рекомендую, как вариант, создать нового пользователя...

Comment: Да, все получилось после того как удалил .Xauthority.